# Adobe Alchemy and Llvm 2.5

Tags: actionscript-3, llvm, alchemy

A comment on the Adobe Alchemy mailing list suggests it is possible to get Alchemy working with Llvm 2.7 (instead of 2.1 in the Alchemy download).

Does anyone know if this is true and if so any tips on how to go about it?

**UPDATE:** the thread is [here](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/212710) and it seems i read it wrong. I missed that the op is the developer of Alchemy talking about an internal Adobe version. I would love an update!

Comment: See my comment on the answer below. The reason why the alchemy toolkit hasn't been publicly updated is because it has been refined and is currently serving as the flash to iphone compiler as well as the flash to android compiler ( I think, iphone for sure). Releasing the now updated toolkit would be a direct blow to the top two selling features of the flash IDE now. So essentially you can kiss any hope of ever seeing alchemy being updated goodbye. The only reason it's even still available is probably to comply with licenses so they can use it internally.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried getting LLVM upgraded (see this [thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2123452#2123452)).  The short answer is that I don't think you can.  The newer LLVMs output a different kind of intermediate opcodes, which the Alchemy backend plugin doesn't expect.

Comment: Agreed. The method used with the latest alchemy release is hack-ish, and takes an existing IR output that the actionscript compiler outputs and just modifies it to what that current version of the LLVM expects. These codes change which is why there are interfaces provided by the LLVM to do this type of conversion instead of directly "by hand" like the way the adobe team originally did it. Make no mistake though, the alchemy toolkit has been upgraded very much, just not publicly released. If you want to get an updated version, download and decompile the packager for iphone SDK for flash.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your comment?  Are you using the iphone packager to do alchemy?

Comment: Not yet, working on it though. There is a class inside the PFI.jar that will accept actionscript bytecode as input and emit LLVM IR so theoretically, it is legally possible (since you're not decompiling anything) to create a hybrid toolchain comprised of the existing public alchemy SDK and the PFI.